# Does Android prefer the drawable folder if it first finds a resource there?

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, android-drawable

I have put an image in drawable folder and in `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi` folders.

I know that android uses the image that is compatible with the screen density, but i want to know what android will do if the same image is in `drawable` folder, does android give priority to `drawable` folder, or it will follow the same approach, and does not check `drawable` folder first for image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prefers the most specific.  So it will use the drawable folder only if there is no override in another folder.  The drawable folder is a good place to put things like xml drawables which usually aren't effected much by dpi, screen size, etc.

Answer (score 7):

`res/drawable/` is a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`, for backwards compatibility from back in the day before we had densities. Bitmaps put in `res/drawable/` will be treated as if they were in `res/drawable-mdpi/`.

This is why so many developers get screwed over when they put bitmaps in `res/drawable/` and call it good — Android treats it as `-mdpi` and upscales for higher densities, often resulting in `OutOfMemoryError`.

IMHO, it is a code smell to have bitmaps in `res/drawable/`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this, but your answer raised another question in my mind, Why scaling up the image will lead to `OutOfMemoryError`, what my understanding so far is that if you open a larger image on smaller device, it can cause memory/performance issue, but how opening a smaller image on bigger device can cause `OutOfMemoryError`. Thanks

Comment: @Kirmani88: I said "upscales for higher densities". Screen size and screen density are not related.

Comment: @CommonsWare How could you find out that drawable is actually a synonym for drawable-mdpi?

Comment: @ThuyTrinh: If you are asking how I know, this came up in discussion years ago. If you are asking how one could confirm this behavior... you could try using `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` and see the resolution of the resulting `Bitmap` on devices with varying densities. If `res/drawable/` is treated as a source of `-mdpi` density drawables, then the `Bitmap` when loaded on an `-mdpi` environment should exactly match the file's resolution, and an `-xhdpi` environment should result in a `Bitmap` with double the length and double the width.

Comment: You might think why does it matter because ultimately i can resize the image in an ImageView. But the point is if you stick a high res image in `drawable` folder eg. 1000 x 2000, so it would roughly fill the screen of an xxhdpi phone without any scaling. Android treats this as mdpi and automatically scales it up 3x leading to 24MB useage (each pixel is 4 bytes). I believe even if you then scale it back down in the ImageView, you still hit the 24MB useage temporarily, potentially triggering `OutOfMemoryError`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

For example, here are some default and alternative resources:

```
res/
    drawable/ 
        icon.png
        background.png
    drawable-hdpi/ 
        icon.png
        background.png
```

The hdpi qualifier indicates that the resources in that directory are for devices with a high-density screen. The images in each of these drawable directories are sized for a specific screen density, but the filenames are exactly the same. This way, the resource ID that you use to reference the icon.png or background.png image is always the same, **but Android selects the version of each resource that best matches the current device, by comparing the device configuration information with the qualifiers** in the resource directory name.